# missing permissions to create folder from java application

Tags: linux

I am setting up a spring boot application and when running it, it should generate a folder in the source directory (see step 3: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-h2-database)

But when running the application I receive the following error:

```
org.h2.message.DbException: Log file error: "/data/sample.trace.db", cause: "org.h2.message.DbException: Error while creating file ""/data"" [90062-200]" [90034-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:194)
    at org.h2.message.TraceSystem.logWritingError(TraceSystem.java:294)
    at org.h2.message.TraceSystem.openWriter(TraceSystem.java:315)
    at org.h2.message.TraceSystem.writeFile(TraceSystem.java:263)
    at org.h2.message.TraceSystem.write(TraceSystem.java:247)
    at org.h2.message.Trace.error(Trace.java:194)
```

it seems to be a permission problem but I do not understand why. My current user, has admin permissons. What am I missing here?

Comment: You're probably not allowed as a normal user to create top level directories. Use e.g., `/tmp/data` instead of `/data`. Or drop the trailing slash.

Comment: You need to learn that on Unix/BSD, and Linux, too, they are "directories" and not the user Windows-ism of "folders" which is not the same thing.

Comment: @Robert yes, you are correct. But what could be the reason? My user has admin privileges.

Answer (score 0):

When I encounter this problem on my machine I proceed through following steps:

1. If I don't know what **user & group I am** right now: `$whoami && groups`
2. **What user is the program** executed with (I'm not into Java so eg. PHP "`echo exec('whoami');`")
3. Who has **access** to the directory: `$ls -la`

- 3.1 If only owner has access and you are not the owner: `$chown user:group file`
- 3.2 If group and owner should have access consider: `$chmod 770 file`